# Bootstrap 4, Popper.JS, and WebPack -- "import and export may appear only with sourceType: module"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I had a project working perfectly with `bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha6`. I just tried upgrading this project to `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta` and noticed the new dependency on Popper.js instead of Tether.

I updated my package.json to include `popper.js@^1.11.0` and updated my code from:

```
window.Tether = require("tether");
require("bootstrap");
```

to:

```
window.Popper = require("popper.js");
require("bootstrap");
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
./~/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (2429:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2610:13)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:782:16)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:690:23)
    at Parser.parse (/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:543:15)
    at parse (/project/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3670:37)
    at module.exports (/project/node_modules/falafel/index.js:22:15)
    at /project/node_modules/static-module/index.js:30:13
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:36:43)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:185:7)
 @ ./resources/assets/js/common/bootstrap.js 12:16-36
 @ ./resources/assets/js/website/app.js
```

I'm not super familiar with or good at using WebPack. It was forced upon me by Laravel 5.4, so I've just been floundering up until this point. My `webpack.config.js` file looks like so:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js/,
        loader: "transform?brfs"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it webpack 1 or 2+? If 1, you may need a Babel loader to handle the ESM build. Or use the UMD build provided by Popper.js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the ***umd*** build which is located in the `dist/umd` folder of popper.js: (`dist/umd/popper.js` or `dist/umd/popper.min.js`)

The following answer helped me with an issue with bootstrap 4 and popper, take a look here: [How to use popper 1.12.0 with bootstrap 4.0 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694811/how-to-use-popper-1-12-0-with-bootstrap-4-0-beta)

Also, I'm using AngularCLI, which uses Webpack. Changing path from the `dist` to `dist/umd` has solved my issue.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 8):

Use the UMD distributive target: https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js#dist-targets

Comment: I'm torn on which answer to accept because you both gave the "UMD" response which fixed my issue, however the other answer lead me more directly to the solution (referencing the `dist/umd` folder) so I'm going to accept it as I believe it will be more helpful to others who stumble upon this

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the UMD distribution which is provided popper.js folder in node module and point your angular-cli.json to your popper.js path.