# How to use Popper.js with Bootstrap 4 beta

Tags: bootstrap-4, popper.js

I'm old school, so I downloaded the source code to 1.12.0 and then did the following:

```
<script src="/popper.js-1.12.0/dist/popper.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

But I'm getting:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

on line `2294` where it says:

```
export default Popper;
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You want to use the dist target specified in the [`package.json` file as `main` entry](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/blob/master/packages/popper/package.json#L27).

In this case, you are looking for the `umd` build ([`dist/umd/popper.js`](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/tree/v1.12.6/dist/umd))

### What's UMD?

> The [UMD pattern](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) typically attempts to offer compatibility with the most popular script loaders of the day (e.g RequireJS amongst others). In many cases it uses AMD as a base, with special-casing added to handle CommonJS compatibility.

This means that an UMD bundle can be loaded via `<script>` tag and get injected inside the global scope (`window`), but also work if required with a CommonJS loader such as RequireJS.

Answer (score 24):

#### Popper requires that you use the file under the **umd** path with Bootstrap 4.

Either of these CDN versions will work:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.5/umd/popper.min.js

Other answers/comments mention the version, *however the problem is not related to versioning*.

It's never a bad practice to use [Bootstrap's example of including popper](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) because it should always work.  Bootstrap 4 as of now recommends popper 1.11 which is a safe choice, however version 1.12.5 should work fine as well.

Side note: Why the confusion with umd, esm, and plain ol' popper files? The intention is flexible module packaging, but in reality it could be made simpler. [This post](https://medium.com/webpack/the-state-of-javascript-modules-4636d1774358) explains some of the issues with new module types.

Comment: with SRI: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha256-98vAGjEDGN79TjHkYWVD4s87rvWkdWLHPs5MC3FvFX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you use the Popper.js version referenced in the Bootstrap docs.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js

Comment: I use popper 1.12.x and it error "SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module". Change to 1.11.0 and it works. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't believe it's the version that matters, it's the "umd" part of the url that gets missed when simply copying the script tag from cdnjs. `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.4/umd/popper.min.js` works, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.4/popper.min.js` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

As per the [popper docs](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/tree/master/packages/popper#dist-targets):

> Popper.js is currently shipped with 3 targets in mind: UMD, ESM and
>   ESNext.
>
> UMD - Universal Module Definition: AMD, RequireJS and globals;
>
> ESM - ES Modules: For webpack/Rollup or browser supporting the spec;
>
> ESNext: Available in dist/, can be used with webpack and
>   babel-preset-env; Make sure to use the right one for your needs. If
>   you want to import it with a  tag, use UMD.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Tried different approaches, but this one worked for me.
Read the instruction from http://getbootstrap.com/.

Copy the CDN links (jQuery, Popper and Bootstrap) in same order (it is important) as given.

[image: Bootstrap CDN links]

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use bootstrap's bundle version and your good!

```
<script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="./node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"></script> -->
<!-- <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Fez Vrasta.

If retrieving popper through NuGet Package Manager within Visual Studio make sure your popper.js script reference path is using the **umd** folder:

MVC ASP.Net BundleConfig example:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/umd/popper.js", //path with umd
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Direct script reference example:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/umd/popper.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate Containers:

If you followed the accepted answer and your tool-tips are still in the wrong place, it *might* be because you have a different container for each tool-tip.

I would try this to allow the tool-tip to be placed *near the parent of the element*:

```
const initializeTooltips = function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function() {
        $(this).tooltip({container: $(this).parent()});
    });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    initializeTooltips();
});
```

Try It yourself on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u53jpdnm/).