# uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export its happen at popper.js:2371

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datatables, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I am new to bootstrap and jquery. I'm trying to use datatables feature like sorting , while I run my codes I get this error in console:

```
uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export at popper.js:2371
```

my popper.js version is: 1.14.3
and I render it in my layout like this :

```
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_navbar")
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year -www.vidly.com @*My ASP.NET Application*@</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
 @*   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")*@
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js")

  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/popper.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootbox.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/respond.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js")
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DataTables/DataTables.bootstrap.js")
    @*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")*@

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

and [image: this is] the picture of my browser,
Here I have 2 question :1.why I get this error :

```
uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export at popper.js:2371
```

2.Why datatables feature like pages number and sorting methods are irregular in my browser.(as you have seen in picture )
this is my css bundles :

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(

                      "~/Content/bootstrap-lumen.css",
                      "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
```

I render it in my _layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")*@
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css") 
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_navbar")
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year -www.vidly.com @*My ASP.NET Application*@</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

TIA

Comment: your bootstrap is not loaded properly, please check your nav-menu, it must show properly if it has loaded the bootstrap correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Unexpected token export at popper.js* on bundling indicates that Popper library requires [UMD build version](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) of corresponding JS file, which wrongly set here (probably you're using ESNext version):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/popper.js")
```

The UMD version import is necessary since we want to import it with `<script>` tag generated by bundling mechanism (`System.Web.Optimization`) as written in [official page](https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/).

> If you want to import it with a `<script>` tag, use UMD.

Here are those steps to use UMD version with MVC bundling:

1) Get UMD version from **dist** package here: https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.4/dist/umd/

2) Save the UMD package inside `/Scripts/umd` folder.

3) Create JS bundles in `RegisterBundles()` method with specified paths like example below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-*",
    // other jQuery scripts here
));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Scripts/umd/popper.js", // set to UMD version
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootbox.js",
    "~/Scripts/respond.js",

    // other Bootstrap scripts here
));
```

4) Use `@Scripts.Render()` helper in layout page to include them (note that the script order matters):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

**Note:** If you're looking for [ESNext version of Popper.js](https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.4/dist/popper.js) compared with [UMD version](https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.14.4/dist/umd/popper.js), you will see this header in latter which not exist in former:

```
(function (global, factory) {
    typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
    typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
    (global.Popper = factory());
}(this, (function () {
    // skipped for brevity
})));
```

The `function( global, factory )` enables Popper to get injected into global scope using `<script>` tag reference, which becomes possible reason of UMD bundle usage.

About your second issue, sounds like the CSS files are not included properly. Refer to [Bundling and Minification section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) to import CSS bundles.

Related issues:

[How to use Popper.js with Bootstrap 4 beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694811/how-to-use-popper-js-with-bootstrap-4-beta)

[popper.js in bootstrap 4 gives SyntaxError Unexpected token export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46459767/popper-js-in-bootstrap-4-gives-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export/46460112)

Comment: thanks dear tetsuya you solved my first porblem but for my 2nd problem I added my css  bundles to question can you guide me more?