# Adding external js file in vue cli

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I am trying to add external js file in vue **app.vue**. But it's not working. I followed this as adding external style sheet. Also want to include in a **component** for another js file. I am beginner in vue js. How can I include this. Thanks in advance . I am using vue cli

App.vue

```
  <template>
    <div id="app">
       <router-view/>
    </div>
  </template>

 <script>
    @import './assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js';
    @import './assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js';
    @import './assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js';
  </script>
```

Comment: maybe this is what your looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45694811/how-to-use-popper-js-with-bootstrap-4-beta

Answer (score 3):

One of these

```js
<script src='./assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js'></script>
<script src='./assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='./assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js'></script>
```

or

```js
<script>
export default
{
   import './assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js';
   import './assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js';
   import './assets/js/jquery.slimscroll.js';
}
</script>
```

But it would be better if you import scripts like these into your `public/index.html` file.

Comment: Thanks for reply. AS per your instruction I add those in **public/index.html** . Like **<link href='@/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel="stylesheet">** and **<script src='./assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js'></script>** . but it's not working

Comment: You should check whether these are the right paths to use - the paths in **public/index.html** are relative to this file at the time of its deployment while the paths in your ES6 JavaScript module are relative to that file (probably inside **src** folder)

Comment: I also tried with that. **<link href='src/assets/styles/style.css' rel="stylesheet">** but not working. folder structure is  **src/assets/styles/style.css** and **src/assets/js/popper.min.js**

Comment: How can I access files from **src/...** because my index file is in **public** folder.

Comment: You have to put such files inside the **public** folder.

Comment: I did that. It's working if i place all content in one component . But when I segregate them into multiple component and combine , that time **js** file not working. But contents show successfully